# Why S=B(0;1) is a open set?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If I have a $S=B(0,1)$ usual notation for Ball with center at $0$ and with radius  $=1$,

then it is an open set in $\mathbb{R^2}$.

My book explains that every point of $S$ is the center of a circle lying entirely in $S$.

I don't understand why there exists no point, say a, such that any element in  $B(a;r)$ point is outside of $S$.

Put simply, why does elements in Ball of any point in $S$ have to be lying in $S$?

Comment: The radii of the balls are not arbitrary. Open means that for each point x in S there is a r>0 such that the open ball of center x and radius r is in S.

Answer (score 3):

Why not think it geometrically?Consider any point $(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2$ such that $x^2+y^2<1$

Now what you will have to do is find a suitable radius that such that a open ball with that particular radius completely gets inside $B(0,1)$.

So now try to find that radius by drawing a picture

NOTE:when you take a point $(x,y)$ inside $B(0,1)$ then what you have to do is find an open ball with centre at $(x,y)$ to fit inside $B(0,1)$.So find $R=min\{d((x,y),(0,0)),d(x,y),(1,1))\}$ and take the radius say $=\frac{R}{2}>0$

Comment: Can you explain more what "geometrically" means? for any point satisfying this inequality, why does "ball" of that point have to be inside of this inequality?

Comment: yes I can.it is not that the ball will lie inside it ,the fact is you will have to find one such that to prove its openness.Let me add something to my answer

Comment: Tell me if it is all right for you @Nancy

Comment: Now I got it, so for some points in B(0;1), radius has to be extremely small so that elements in that ball are inside of B(0.1). And, for this inequality, every point in that ball is interior, and any points outside of that circle are exterior? But, seems like if that's the case no boundary exists...? Thank you so much

Comment: glad to help you @Nancy Also please consider accepting it if you feel it has helped you

Comment: I am willing to accept it , thank you. One more thing, though, for inequality x^2+y^2<1 what would be the boundary? I guess exterior is every point outside the interior so, exterior is x^2+y^2 greater or equal to 1, then it seems like there is no boundary?

Comment: also, where is "accept", i cant find it..

Comment: there is a tick mark below the answer clicking it helps

Comment: If you want the boundary consider $B[0,1]\setminus B(0,1)$ i.e the closed ball minus the open ball

Answer (score 1):

The reason is triangle inequality.

Assume that $x$ is a point in $B(0,1)$. Then we can consider $B(x,1-d(0,x))$ where $d(0,x)$ is the distance from $x$ to $0$.

Assume that $y\in B(x,1-d(0,x))$. Then $$\underbrace{d(0,y)\leq d(0,x)+d(x,y)}_{\text{triangle inequality}}<d(0,x)+(1-d(0,x))=1$$ Therefore $y\in B(0,1)$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, one thing that I can't understand is that why the radius of B(x,1-d(0.x) has to be less than 1?

Comment: @Nancy In this example it is smaller than $1$. In general it may not have to be. In some other spaces with some fancy metrics (ways to measure distances) sometimes the ball inside has larger radius. One important detail in the definition is that it says "there is some ball with that center inside the other ball". It means that it is enough to show **one** ball that works.