# The set of all exterior points is an open set

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

> Let $S$ be a subset of $R$. Then the set of all exterior points of $S$ is an open set.

My proof is as follows:

> For any element $x$ in $\operatorname{ext}(S)$ (the set of all exterior points of $S$), $B(x;r)$ for $r>0$ is not a subset of $S$. We know that since $B(x;r)$ is open set, any point in $B(x;r)$ is exterior point of $S$ and thus there is $h>0$ such that $B(x_1;h)$ is not a subset of $S$. $B(x_1;h)$ is a subset of $B(x;r)$, implying $\operatorname{ext}(S)$ is open set.

Is this proof valid? If not can someone help me modify this more properly?

Comment: What is your definition of the exterior?

Comment: Given S subset of R, exterior point of S is that there is a ball with r>0 such that B(x;r) is not a subset of S?

Comment: @nany Using this definition, $\operatorname{ext} S$ is a neighbourhood of every point inside it, so $\operatorname{ext} S$ is open.

Comment: Your proof is close. However it is not enough for the ball to not be a subset of S; each element must not be an element of S.

Answer (score 1):

The **exterior** is `the interior of the complement of the set`.

We need to show that every point of the exterior is contained in a ball that consists entirely of points in the exterior.

Recall that **interior** is `the set of all point that can be covered by a ball completely contained in the set`.

So, if $x\in\text{ext}(S)$ then there is a ball $B(x,r)$ such that $B(x,r)$ is contained in the complement of $S$, i.e. it doesn't intersect $S$ (*notice how doesn't intersect is not the same as is not a subset*). Each point $y\in B(x,r)$ is contained in a ball $B(y,r-d(x,y))$ that is contained in $B(x,r)$, and therefore also contained in the complement of $S$. Therefore $y$ is also in the interior of the complement of $S$, i.e. $y$ is also in $\text{ext}(S)$.

Therefore $\text{ext}(S)$ is open.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I almost understood your work and your notice too!. Can I also say that B(x.r) is open and therefore y in B(x.r) has a ball contained in B(x.r)?

Comment: @Nancy Yes, you can.

Comment: Would you mind If I asked you why B(x.r) is open though? , I know it because there is a theorem but no specific proof of it is shown

Comment: @Nancy See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1112954/203995).

Answer (score 0):

An easy way :

suppose $x\in Ext(S)$

then $\exists r_x>0 $ such that $B(x,r_x)\subseteq X\setminus S$

Now it remains to show only that $B(x,r_x)\subseteq Ext(S)$

let $y\in B(x,r_x)$ and since $B(x,r_x)$ is open then $\exists s_y>0$ such that $B(y,r_y)\subset B(x,r_x)\subseteq X\setminus S$

thus we have for any $y\in B(x,r_x)$ we have $B(y,r_y)\subseteq X\setminus S$

thus $y\in Ext(S)$.Hence $B(x,r_x)\subseteq Ext(S)$

Answer (score 0):

x is in the exterior iff it has neighborhood B(x) disjoint from x iff  it has B(x) subset of the exterior.  The exterior is U {B(x)| x is in the exterior} is the union of open nghbrhoods, is open.